# What is this canonical form of matrix called?

Tags: linear-algebra, terminology, numerical-linear-algebra

I am reading Rao, R.A., & Bhimasankaram, P. (2000). *Linear algebra*, and it has a habit of using non-standard terminology. This is what it calls *Hermite canonical form*:

> A square matrix $\mathbf H$ of order $n$ is said to be in Hermite
> canonical form iff:
>
> 1. $\mathbf H$ is upper triangular,
> 2. each diagonal entry of $\mathbf H$ is $0$ or $1$,
> 3. the $i$-th row of $\mathbf H$ is null if $\mathbf H(i,i) = 0$, and
> 4. the $i$-th column of $\mathbf H$ is $\mathbf e_i$ if $\mathbf H(i,i) = 1$.

This seems to be the same as the definition of reduced echelon form with the exception of the constraint that the matrix is square and (3.). However, when I look up anything related to Hermite canonical form, I get something to do with matrix over integers, and a completely different definition. So either the authors are using that definition from a different perspective, or Hermite canonical form refers to two different things, or they are calling something completely different Hermite canonical form.

The authors use this matrix in checking consistency of a system, by augmenting the output vector to the coefficient matrix, and performing the algorithm to obtain its "Hermite" form. If the "Hermite" form of the coefficient matrix has a null row, but the corresponding entry in the transformed output column is not $0$, then the system is inconsistent; and if it is consistent, a general solution of the system is:
$$
\mathbf d + (\mathbf I - \mathbf H) \mathbf z 
$$
where $\mathbf d$ is the transformed form of the output column (and in fact a particular solution), $\mathbf H$ is the "Hermite" form of the coefficient matrix if it is square, $\mathbf z$ is any suitable vector. If the matrix is non square, they apply some different algorithm where they get a similar (as in the English similar) non-square matrix and exclude extra rows (if any), but that's too involved, so I will ignore that.

(edit)
If the matrix is not square, it seems they just act as if there were some extra null columns/row to make it square.

Also if we augment an identity matrix, the transformed identity matrix will correspond to the generalised inverse of the coefficient matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the terminology may not be totally standard.

Glancing through my bookshelf, in Nering's *Linear Algebra and Matrix Theory*, 2nd ed. (1970), we have on p. 54

> **Theorem 5.1.** Given any $m\times n$ matrix $A$ of rank $\rho$, there exists a non-singular $m\times m$ matrix $Q$ such that $A'=Q^{-1}A$ has the following form:
> (1) There is at least one non-zero element in each of the first $\rho$ rows of $A'$, and the elements in all remaining rows are zero.
> (2) The first non-zero element appearing in row $i$ ($i\le\rho$) is a $1$ appearing in column $k_i$ where $k_1<k_2<\cdots<k_{\rho}$.
> (3) In column $k_i$ the only non-zero element is the $1$ in row $i$.

The author then writes

> We say that a matrix satisfying the conditions of Theorem 5.1 is in *Hermite normal form*. Often this form is called a *row-echelon form*. And sometimes the term, Hermite normal form, is reserved for a square matrix containing exactly the numbers that appear on the form we obtained in Theorem 5.1 with the change that row $i$ beginning with a $1$ in column $k_i$ is moved down to row $k_i$. Thus each non-zero row begins on the main diagonal and each column with a $1$ on the main diagonal is otherwise zero.

The latter form seems to align with what your book calls *Hermite canonical form*.